# matching all 5 digits numbers other than 3 specific ones-without negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

So I am trying to match with any 5 digits number other than *10000*,*11000*,*68000*. With negative lookbehind, lookaround etc. this code does exactly what I want

`^[0-9]{5}(?<!10000|11000|68000)$`

.However, I would like to do it without using lookbehind. Is there any nice way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Using a negative lookahead you mean? You can switch it around. `^(?!(?:10000|11000|68000)$)\d{5}$` https://regex101.com/r/WVpqQ3/1.

Comment: Can you use negative lookahead? `^(?!(?:1[01]|68)000$)[0-9]{5}$`

Comment: It is possible to write this pattern without lookarounds, but the pattern would be rather long and ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match all 5 digit numbers excluding your few listed
excludes numbers *10000, 11000, and 68000*

The ranges are:

00000 - 09999
10001 - 10999
11001 - 67999
68001 - 99999

```
^(?:0\d{4}|(?:1000[1-9]|100[1-9]\d|10[1-9]\d{2})|(?:1100[1-9]|110[1-9]\d|11[1-9]\d{2}|1[2-9]\d{3}|[2-5]\d{4}|6[0-7]\d{3})|(?:6800[1-9]|680[1-9]\d|68[1-9]\d{2}|69\d{3}|[7-9]\d{4}))$
```

viewing

```
 ^ 
 (?:
      0 \d{4} 
   |  (?:
           1000 [1-9] 
        |  100 [1-9] \d 
        |  10 [1-9] \d{2} 
      )
   |  (?:
           1100 [1-9] 
        |  110 [1-9] \d 
        |  11 [1-9] \d{2} 
        |  1 [2-9] \d{3} 
        |  [2-5] \d{4} 
        |  6 [0-7] \d{3} 
      )
   |  (?:
           6800 [1-9] 
        |  680 [1-9] \d 
        |  68 [1-9] \d{2} 
        |  69 \d{3} 
        |  [7-9] \d{4} 
      )
 )
 $
```